# React, Node.js, Express, Heroku, GoDaddy redirect problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, dns

So I've built an online platform with React using Node.js and Express for the backend. Everything runs as it should on local and on my Heroku URL. Now I want to add a custom domain using GoDaddy, but it is just not working.

I've got my SSL certificate with Heroku and everything there seems to be correct. However, on the GoDaddy side, everything seems to be correct too. I've set my www CNAME in GoDaddy to my Heroku DNS URL. Also, I redirect my root domain to my www.domain and that seems to work fine too. But when I check my `www.domain.com` it says the location is domain.com which is not correct I guess.

The root domain is `studoo.app`

[image: Postman screenshot of GET request studoo.app]

the `studoo.app` request location is set to `https://www.studoo.app` which is right because I've set that 301 redirect in GoDaddy

But when I go to `www.studoo.app` the location is set to `studoo.app` which I don't understand

[image: Postman screenshot of GET request www.studoo.app]

when visiting `www.studoo.app` I get the **"Your connection is not private"** error.

[image: Google chrome privacy error]

If anyone could help me out, please reach out. I've been searching for a week now ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have both `studoo.app` and `www.studoo.app` as domains on heroku. On go daddy I would point both the root and www to the heroku URL